# Cannot go to detailspage when click link from other app by using Deeplinks plugin

Tags: cordova, routes, deep-linking, ionic5

I use ionic 5 cordova. I have done setup everything for using plugin Deeplinks. The problem here when I open the app it will go to homepage but not detailspage. And if I click link *(mydomain/details/1)* target for detailspage it will go to homepage. Where is my mistake? Please help me for this problem. Thank you.

## app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'details/:slug',
    loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then( m => m.DetailsPageModule)
  },
```

## app.component.ts

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {   
    this.setupDeeplinks();  
    });
  }

  setupDeeplinks() {
    this.deeplinks.route({
      '/details/:slug': DetailsPage //import page at top page
     }).subscribe(
      match => {   
        alert(" match")
      },
      nomatch => { 
        alert(" no match")
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: hmmm...are you sure you have <router-outlet> in app.component.html?

Comment: do you mean this?  <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>. yes i have in app.component.html